# Implementing SwiftUI list items aligned with image

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, swiftui-list

Is there some tricky way to implement a list in [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/) with a set of 'continuous' images on its left perfectly aligned with the text?

I am not looking for code, but hints on ways to achieve this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the linked post, they are using a `VStack` & a `ScrollView`. However, this can be done using a `List`:

[image: Preview]

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(["pencil", "ruler", "book"], id: \.self) { item in
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Image(systemName: item)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
                            .frame(width: 5, height: 50) //you can remove the height to make it dynamic & use padding for the spacing.
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Day 1")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                        Text("This is a long text as for testing the layout of the cell.")
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .opacity(0.7)
                    }
                }
            }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 15))
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        }.listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```